# Is this possible to send FCM push Notification through backend server to flutter for scheduled the notification or this can be possible in flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using firebase cloud messaging push notification service to send notifications in a flutter, but I want to send notifications. I am using FCM as a push notification, but the problem is that I can't schedule the notification in FCM.

For example: if I need to call a customer at 4:30 pm, I want to show a push notification at 4:00 pm as a reminder that I have to call a customer at 4:30.

I just want to know if I can achieve with the back end.
I am using local push notifications but the problem is when my app is in the terminated state I cannot receive a push notification, so I am trying to use a backend server so any can explain the logic.

Comment: What have you tried? There are three ways to approach this. 1. Through your backend logic (I use nodejs), you can set up your logic and have triggers to send notifications. 2. Using firebase dashboard, set a notification and schedule it (it's quite limiting though) 3. Use a package like https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications you can set up your scheduled   notifications direct from your flutter code

Comment: Yup, sending a reminder sounds totally possible. I recommend giving it a try, and reporting back if you have trouble implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [Flutter plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_notification_scheduler) for this